# Chrome extension Oauth2 Spotify Api

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, oauth, spotify

I'm building a Spotify api chrome extension without a backend so all the api calls are done with fetch. On my localhost in dev mode the application works perfectly fine, but once I load it into chrome the callback doesn't work it says invalid redirect uri. I tried looking up online how to implement it but I could find any clear answers. I found some answers about webflowauth but not sure how I would implement it without a backend. Is there any methods that I can use to do without creating a backend, Thanks. (Also the redirect uri is not the one used for the extension I was just using it to test it in dev mode)

```
function authorization() {
  const clientId = "client_id";
  const redirectUri = "http://127.0.0.1:4173";
  let codeVerify = generateRandomString(128);

  generateCodeVerify(codeVerify).then((codeChallenge) => {
    let state = generateRandomString(16);
    let scope =
      "streaming app-remote-control user-modify-playback-state user-read-currently-playing playlist-read-private user-read-email user-read-private user-read-playback-state";

    localStorage.setItem("code_verifier", codeVerify);

    let args = new URLSearchParams({
      response_type: "code",
      client_id: clientId,
      scope: scope,
      redirect_uri: redirectUri,
      state: state,
      code_challenge_method: "S256",
      code_challenge: codeChallenge,
    });

    window.location = "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?" + args;
  });

  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  let code = urlParams.get("code");
  let codeVerifier = localStorage.getItem("code_verifier");

  let body = new URLSearchParams({
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
    code: code,
    redirect_uri: redirectUri,
    client_id: clientId,
    code_verifier: codeVerifier,
  });

  const response = fetch("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
    body: body,
  })
    .then((response) => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP status " + response.status);
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      localStorage.setItem("access_token", data.access_token);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error:", error);
    });
}
```

I tried using the https://.chromiumapp.org but it didn't work.

Comment: Also the error I get is a 400 bad request when I console log it.